# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. in Flutter project

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle

Hello I am new to flutter , and I have this error while trying to run my project.

Can someone help me with it ?

Thank you.

[image: ERROR]

Comment: There are three suggestions under "Try:"; have you tried any of them?

Comment: It could be that there was an internet error when trying to load kotlin which is on line 25 of build.gradle. Try giving a higher permission when running the project, for example opening an admin console or sudo and running flutter run in the repo.

Comment: @prosfilaes I tried it but it doesn't work

Comment: @Chance I tried the command " sudo flutter run " but it doesn't wanna work

Answer (score 1):

If faced same issue, this solution worked for me
In android/build.gradle file:

in buildscript change the following:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
     }
```

and in `android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties` file:

add this line:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip
```